# Pandas: unexpected keyword argument 'sort' when running on S3

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-s3

I am using the following line of code to check if all my columns exist, and if not to create them and fill with 0

```
pivot_df = pivot_df.reindex(pivot_df.columns.union(cols, sort=False), axis=1, fill_value=0)
```

The script is running on S3 and in the logs I get this error:

> line 125, in run
> pivot_df = pivot_df.reindex(pivot_df.columns.union(cols, sort=False), axis=1, fill_value=0)
>
> TypeError: union() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sort'

This is clearly the problem, but what is odd is that if I run the code manually I get no error and it saves on S3.

After same research I found that this bug is caused by pandas' update, and most of the solutions are referring to reinstalling `scorecardpy`.

I am not completely sure if it's my case since it runs manually and 99% of the time errors pop up due to my lack of experience.

Can someone, please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: ``sort`` was added in 0.24.0 [union](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.union.html), check the version of pandas.

Comment: If I remove sort = False, wil by default set it to True and the error will still occuer correct?

Comment: @Christian: Not if it doesn't exist.  What version of pandas is being used on your S3?

Comment: So the pandas version is 0.23.4. This was the problem

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Sushanth and BrenBarn' comments I will post the answer in case someone else encounters the same problem.

As the guys said in the comments the problem raises due the pandas version.
Since it's running on my local pc I checked my pandas version with `pip show pandas` in the pandas command prompt and changed the one from the requirements file with my own. After this just pushed again to S3 and git will automatically install the new dependencies.

In the requirements file it should be like this

```
pandas==0.24.2
```